# How to perform a method on multiple arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

The method takes in one array as an argument. I will be trying to implement this in Java. I believe it can be achieved by making an array list, but I am drawing a blank.

Idea:

```
for(i = 0; i < amount of arrays; i++)
{
  Method(array[]);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Maybe working through the Java tutorials, on both loops and arrays, would be more useful to you than anything anyone can tell you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better use `ArrayList` like:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
```

Then:

```
for(ArrayList list : lists) {
    method(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `List<myType[]>` or an array of arrays `myType[][]`.

You can use basically any `Iterable<myType[]>` that suits your needs.